# Android web service json response merged super script commentsÂ®Â

Tags: android, android-volley, ascii, unicode-string, superscript

I am calling same json web services https url calling from different pages. 
For first page, am getting proper response string from web service like comments®.
For another page, am calling same web service url, am getting server response string with superscript merged. ex: commentsÂ®Â

using Volley web services, application/json, Https Post method

Note: for same ws calling from IOS, they are getting proper response without superscripts.
I have tried to add UTF-8 in https calling web services, its not workout.

How to avoid this super script text.

Thanks Guys

Comment: Even I am facing this issue. Did you found any solution?

Comment: Please add some codding part and response from API

Comment: Usually, when two different calls to the same url produces two different responses it is because the developer did not use the same code base. :: In order to determine why you are getting two different responses you will need to post the code base to BOTH of your requests.

Comment: try clearing the cache.